# Updating O365 License "Microsoft Stream for O365 ES SKU"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update multiple users at once with the license "Microsoft Stream for O365 ES SKU", I am stuck on getting the specific license. I have a text file with users and I know how to update users with a license from the SkuPart Number

```
$O365Users = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\O365 users.txt'

foreach ($user in $O365Users)
{
   Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user -AddLicenses "Location:ENTERPRISEPREMIUM"
}
```

But I'm trying to update each user with the "Microsoft Stream for o365 ES SKU" object under the Enterprisepremium SKU. If I try to update them with the SkuID Stream it just gives them the Microsoft Stream Trial license.

Anyone have any ideas?

results for Get-MsolSubscription | Select SkuPartNumber,Status,IsTrial

```
SkuPartNumber                  Status IsTrial
-------------                  ------ -------
STREAM                        Enabled   False
ENTERPRISEPREMIUM             Enabled   False
POWERAPPS_INDIVIDUAL_USER     Enabled   False
FLOW_FREE                     Enabled   False
POWERAPPS_VIRAL               Enabled   False
DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1       Enabled   False
Dynamics_365_Onboarding_SKU   Enabled   False
POWER_BI_STANDARD             Enabled   False
INTUNE_A                    Suspended    True
MCOPSTNC                      Enabled   False
TEAMS_EXPLORATORY             Enabled    True
EMS                           Enabled   False
TEAMS_COMMERCIAL_TRIAL        Enabled    True
```

Comment: please show the results of `Get-MsolSubscription | Select SkuPartNumber,Status,IsTrial`

Comment: Added results to the main question for you

Comment: thanks, also please show the results of `Get-MsolAccountSku`